# Drop table using Pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

The `SparkSession.catalog` object has a bunch of methods to interact with the metastore, namely:

```py
['cacheTable',
 'clearCache',
 'createExternalTable',
 'createTable',
 'currentDatabase',
 'dropGlobalTempView',
 'dropTempView',
 'isCached',
 'listColumns',
 'listDatabases',
 'listFunctions',
 'listTables',
 'recoverPartitions',
 'refreshByPath',
 'refreshTable',
 'registerFunction',
 'setCurrentDatabase',
 'uncacheTable']
```

Unfortunately, there seems to have no programmatic way to drop a table.

There are multiple ways to achieve this like

```py
spark.sql(f"drop table my_table")
```

or

```py
spark._jsparkSession.sharedState().externalCatalog().dropTable(db, table, True, True)
```

but they look a little bit hackish compared to a simple, nonetheless missing, `dropTable` method?

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK from the above approaches mentioned are most commonly used ones. No other way I feel..

But alternative way I can see from these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/metastore/drop-table-corruptedmetadata)...

you might try this [`org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d8b0914c2e0fdee72a3b9abb2d65283e22b6e8ee/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveUtils.scala) which has goodies  (to drop tables..) for you.

I am not so good in python, you can see below scala example and follow the same way for python.

```
package org.apache.spark.sql.hive {
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
object utils {
    def dropTable(sc: SparkContext, dbName: String, tableName: String, ignoreIfNotExists: Boolean, purge: Boolean): Unit = {
      HiveUtils
          .newClientForMetadata(sc.getConf, sc.hadoopConfiguration)
          .dropTable(dbName, tableName, ignoreIfNotExists, false)
    }
  }
}
```

Caller would be like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.utils
utils.dropTable(sc, "default", "my_table", true, true)
```